# How to change bootstrap column depending on some boolean expression?

Tags: c#, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, blazor

How can I change bootstrap columns depending on the state of some expression?

What I've tried:

```
<div class="@Installation.Fleet.Type.Equals("Vessel") ? col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 : col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">

</div>
```

However in this case, even when @Installation.Fleet.Type.Equals("Vessel") is true, the program always spawns "col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return your classes as string:

```
<div class="@Installation.Fleet.Type.Equals("Vessel") ? "col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12" : "col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12""></div>
```

I tend to always use @() instead of just @ when using ternary operators in razor views, like this:

```
<div class="@(Installation.Fleet.Type.Equals("Vessel") ? "col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12" : "col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12")"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a variable with name of classes like:

```
@{

var classes=@Installation.Fleet.Type.Equals("Vessel") ? "col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12" : "col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12";

}
```

and then:

```
<div class="@classes">

</div>
```